# Twitter Data Analysis using mahout

Tags: hadoop, twitter, hive, mahout, flume

I have collected twitter data using Flume for my current research project. I am thinking of extracting only the texts from these FlumeData files. I want to do mahout text clustering over these tweets. Can anyone suggest me how will I be able to do this ?

So far ,

1. I have used Flume to collect twitter data
2. I parsed my data using Hive and constructed a table tweets consisting of only text tweets.
3. `hive -e 'select * from tweets' > sample.txt` , this gives me all the tweets into a text document.

I used hive here to parse the data .. Is there any other way of doing this? Cos my concern is I would like to split the tweets into multiple text documents so that I can perform mahout text clustering.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far so that people can help you out

Comment: is this a "please do my homework for me, stack overflow" question?

Comment: I just edited my question , could you help me now?